# getting confused with firebase,angular, node js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, firebase

```
I want file structure that angularjs + firebase follows.
File structure for angularjs+nodejs+firebase.
File structure for angularjs+nodejs+firebase+express.
File structure for angularjs+nodejs+firebase+grunt.
File structure for angularjs+nodejs+firebase+yeomen.
```

A fixed file structure convention please
File structure for angularjs+nodejs+mongo+express.
what is JADE.when do we use nodejs while creating simple registration app with angular and nodejs

Comment: The reality of modern development is that it is exceptionally fragmented. There are many tools meant to achieve many things, and there is often overlap when they are used together. It all depends on the what the developer is trying to achieve and their preferences.

Comment: For example, why Jade? Because the developer needed to create templates and that is Jade's purpose. They probably chose Jade specifically because of it's overall popularity and their preference to it's syntax. It could have just as easily been handlebars or any of [a dozen others](https://garann.github.io/template-chooser/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow... where to even start on this one.

Everything you listed are completely separate technologies used to create applications.

[Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/about/) - this a server like Apache that servers up your code. Node as npm which is a package manager.

[Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/introduction) - this is your frontend, the html and what not. It's a single page application framework. It does not require node to run but makes it easier to build apps. Angular uses javascript to change out page content so you site only loads once and does refresh when you change pages.

[Express](http://expressjs.com/) - this is your backend code, it does require node. The frontend talks to Express via Rest calls, then express talks to the database and sends data back to the frontend.

[Firebase](https://www.firebase.com) - this is more or less a database but with some really cool realtime features.

[Bower](https://css-tricks.com/whats-great-bower/) - this is a package manager that is typically used to handle any packages, like Twitter Bootstrap, that you want when create your distribution. The short answer is its really no different than npm.

[grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) - this is task runner that runs on node. it is used to build and server your application. Gulp is becoming more populated than grunt, but grunt can do stuff like run unit test, minify your code, create distributions, and other cool stuff.

[CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) - Create, Read, Update, Delete. They are just functions of your code for like a view page that you can edit.

[Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) - a faster, but stupid way to write html that just makes it harder to read and removes all the html brackets and stuff. Ment for templating

Comment: If you want one of the best angular file structure read John Papa's Style Guide. As a professional angular developer I live by this document. https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide